# Regex formula for string to extract one of two kinds of values

Tags: regex, string, adobe, delimiter

I have values that have single values and concatenated values interspersed. I need to create a regular expression that will evaluate the values and return either the whole number that has no "|" or the first of a group of numbers that are separated by "|" characters.

Example

Existing values

```
12345667D23
3t23456
ab57890
3t23456|ab57890
12345667D23|3t23456|ab57890
```

Transformed values (return either the single value as same or the first of the string up to the "|")

```
12345667D23
3t23456
ab57890
3t23456
12345667D23
```

I am new to regex. I don't have enough experience here... I am not trying to match a string, just return the values (could be numerical, could be alphanumerical, there is not a set string length, just delimited by pipes)

Comment: You could do a replace all `\|.*` with blank https://regex101.com/r/8sax7c/1. Or create a new string based on matches `(?m)^[^|\r\n]*` https://regex101.com/r/24opi6/1 Which one sounds good ?

Comment: Just a fyi. I see your statement that your new to regex. I don't recommend you say that as some will hold up on the hard answers that will show you a complete response, complexities and all. It's better to bite the bullet and take harshness then be in the dark. Your comment below about a white space or trim white space or disqualify elements because of white space can result in several solutions. I suggest you state your problem with all the gory details thrown in when the question is first created. Or quickly revise the question as discovery unveils.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^\|]+
```

Here, `^` matches the start of a line, `[^\|]+` matches a series of characters that aren't pipe (`|`). So the whole expression matches a sequence of characters from the start of a line until `|` or the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great on one file but on the other there is apparently an extra space before the "|"... Is there an elegant way to remove that space?

Comment: I think i figured it out... First I use  ^[^\s]+ as the first rule to classify values that contain a white space, then your original answer as a second rule to classify values that do not contain the white space... it seems to be working.

Comment: If I understand your formatting correctly, you can also try `^[^\s?\|]+`. `\s?` allows for a single space to exist/not exist (match zero or one instance)